# Adding content from one xml file to the other in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I've properties file which has key values of name tag in 2 `xml` files, one is source and other one is destination.

I need to check whether name tag with the same value from properties file is there or not in destination xml, if its there I should not do anything, if its not there the source xml file should be iterated to search for name tag value which is from properties file. Once it found the same name tag should be added from `source.xml` file to `destination.xml` file..

Please do help me on this java code

```
private void updateCofigDestn() throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException, IOException, SAXException {
    prop = loadConfigProperties();
    String ConfigSrcFile = prop.getProperty("ConfigSourceFile");
    String ConfigDesnFile = prop.getProperty("ConfigDestnFile");
    System.out.println("\nConfig  Destn Path update config :: " + ConfigDesnFile);
    File configSrcFile = new File(ConfigSrcFile + "\\config.xml");
    File configDstnFile = new File(ConfigDesnFile + "\\config.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document docSrc = dBuilder.parse(configSrcFile);
    Document docDestn = dBuilder.parse(configDstnFile);

    Set < Object > keys = getAllKeys();
    for (Object k: keys) {
        if (k.toString().startsWith("JDBC")) {
            System.out.println("Inside Keys");
            String key = (String) k;
            keyVal = getPropertyValue(key);
            System.out.println(key + ": " + getPropertyValue(key));


            NodeList listSrc =
                docSrc.getElementsByTagName("jdbc-system-resource");
            NodeList listDsn =
                docDestn.getElementsByTagName("jdbc-system-resource");
            System.out.println("listDsn.item(0)" + listDsn.item(0).getTextContent());

            if (listDsn.item(0) != null) {

                for (int t = 0; t < listDsn.getLength(); t++) {
                    Element elmntDsn1 = (Element) listDsn.item(t);
                    String DsNameDsn1 = elmntDsn1.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
                    System.out.println("DS At DESTN in Update Conf  " + DsNameDsn1);

                    if (keyVal.equalsIgnoreCase(DsNameDsn1)) {} else {

                        for (int temp = 0; temp < listSrc.getLength(); temp++) {
                            Element elmntSrc = (Element) listSrc.item(temp);
                            String DsNameSrc = elmntSrc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
                            //  elmntSrc.getElementsByTagName(keyVal).item(0).getTextContent();

                            // configDestn(keyVal);
                            //System.out.println("value bool >>>>> " +res ) ;

                            if (keyVal.equalsIgnoreCase(DsNameSrc) && keyVal != null) {

                                Node copiedNode = docDestn.importNode(elmntSrc, true);
                                docDestn.getDocumentElement().appendChild(copiedNode);
                                System.out.println(" Updating the destination Config File");
                                TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(docDestn),
                                    new StreamResult(new FileWriter(configDstnFile)));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Destination List is null ");
                for (int temp = 0; temp < listSrc.getLength(); temp++) {

                    Element elmntSrc = (Element) listSrc.item(temp);
                    String elmntValSrc = elmntSrc.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
                    if (keyVal.equalsIgnoreCase(elmntValSrc) &&
                        keyVal != null) {
                        Node copiedNode = docDestn.importNode(elmntSrc, true);
                        docDestn.getDocumentElement().appendChild(copiedNode);
                        System.out.println(" Updating the destination Config File in NULL");
                        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(docDestn),
                            new StreamResult(new FileWriter(configDstnFile)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For ex..

**config.properties**

```
file1 = def
file2 = xyz
file3 = abc
```

**source.xml**

```
<domain>
    <node0>
        <name>xyz</name>
    </node0>
    <node1>
        <name>abc</name>
    </node1>
    <node2>
        <name>def</name>
    </node2>
</domain>
```

**destination.xml**

```
<domain>
    <node1>
        <name>abc</name>
    </node1>
</domain>
```

**Step1:** It takes key value of file 1 'def' from properties file and checks in  destination.xml file, since its not there it will append it.

**Step2:** It takes the next key value of file 2 'xyz' value from properties file and checks in destination.xml file, since its not there it will append it.

**Step3:** It takes the next key value of file 3 'abc' from properties file and checks in destination.xml or not, since its there it will not appended.

And now the `destination.xml` should be looks like,

```
<domain>
    <node1>
        <name>abc</name>
    </node1>
    <node0>
        <name>xyz</name>
    </node0>
    <node2>
        <name>def</name>
    </node2>
</domain>
```

This is my requirement to do in JAVA, I have tried lot of coding.

Please do help me out on this..

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

The mistake you are doing is using inner 3 level nested for-loop whereas only 2 level nested for-loop is required.

The for-loop of `listSrc` should be outside the `destSrc`.

Try this below one.

```
package com.tmp;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Tmp {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {

            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            Document destDocument = builder.parse( new FileInputStream( "D:\\tmp\\destination.xml" ) );
            Document srcDocument = builder.parse( new FileInputStream( "D:\\tmp\\source.xml" ) );

            Element destRootEle = destDocument.getDocumentElement();
            Element srcRootEle = srcDocument.getDocumentElement();

            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.load( new FileInputStream( "D:\\tmp\\config.properties" ) );

            // read properties from config.properties file one by one
            for ( Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet() ) {

                String propVal = (String) entry.getValue();

                NodeList destNodeList = (NodeList) path.evaluate( "//name", destRootEle, XPathConstants.NODESET );

                boolean destNodeNotExist = true;

                // iterate through the destination.xml to check whether property value is exist or not
                for ( int i = 0; i < destNodeList.getLength(); i++ ) {

                    Node node = destNodeList.item( i );

                    if ( propVal.trim().equals( node.getTextContent().trim() ) ) {

                        destNodeNotExist = false;

                        break;
                    }
                }


                // if the property value is not found in destination.xml then check for the node in source.xml to add to the destination.xml
                if ( destNodeNotExist ) {

                    NodeList srcNodeList = (NodeList) path.evaluate( "//name", srcRootEle, XPathConstants.NODESET );

                    for ( int i = 0; i < srcNodeList.getLength(); i++ ) {

                        Node missingNodeToAdd = srcNodeList.item( i );

                        if ( propVal.trim().equals( missingNodeToAdd.getTextContent().trim() ) ) {

                            destRootEle.appendChild( destDocument.adoptNode( missingNodeToAdd.getParentNode() ) );

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // save the changes made to destination.xml file into file system
            Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tr.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes" );
            tr.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes" );
            tr.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8" );
            tr.transform( new DOMSource( destDocument ), new StreamResult( new FileOutputStream( "D:\\tmp\\destination.xml" ) ) );

        } catch ( Exception e ) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Bro, this is the perfect code change u pointed out instead of using nested for loops,